# How to make this change without changing the core?

Tags: widgets, core-modifications

I couldn't find a way to change this in an upgrade friendly way, and I know I mustn't touch the core!

I need to change the value 'number' to 10 in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`

```
wp_tag_cloud( apply_filters('widget_tag_cloud_args', array('taxonomy' => $current_taxonomy, 'number' => 10) ) );
```

How can I do this without changing the core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see there is the [`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) call, with the `$tag` parameter, which is the name of the hook, set to [`widget_tag_cloud_args`](http://hookr.io/3.9.1/filters/apply_filters/widget_tag_cloud_args/). As starting point for getting into hooks, filters and actions I'd suggest you read the codex page about the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/). You can use the hook to change the arguments, e.g. like this:

```
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'wspe160041_change_tag_cloud_number_arg' );
function wspe160041_change_tag_cloud_number_arg( $args ) {
    $args[ 'number' ] = 10;
    return $args;
}
```